# Need help with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Server on my Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: boot, grub2, raspberrypi

I went through the process of getting a bootable microSD card with Ubuntu server on it for an XMPP project I am starting following this guide: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Booting_generic_arm64_ISO_images . However, I am not sure if this is due to me being completely new to Ubuntu, but I can not get it to boot.  When I first start up my rpi, I get to a page where I have to press a key to stop the autobot after it detects usb devices and ethernet, with a command prompt page.  Typing in boot brings me to the GNU GRUB version 2.02 page.  In the section titled Booting and Installation, it says to use a boot parameter which I have no idea what to do with that.  There are also a few more commands it has me do, one of which being set root=(hd1,msdos2).  However, when I type in ls, I only see (memdisk) (hd0) (hd0,msdos1).  The commands after that beginning with linux and initrd says that the command can't be found.  When I attempt to boot it says that I need to load the kernel first.  I apologize if this seems trivial.  Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When reading the instructions for the "Classic Ubuntu deb image" for the Raspberry Pi it states:

> The Raspberry Pi 3 does not (yet) work with official Ubuntu images out of the box, but unofficial images are available.

and You are linking to the ***Booting generic arm64 ISO images***.
Does that mean you downloaded the ubuntu-18.04.1-server-arm64.iso and followed all the instructions regarding:

> - Create a partition with pi firmware/bootloader files
> - Updating the Pi GPU firmware and bootloader files
> - Compile U-boot
> - Copy the device tree blob
> - Copy the ISO contents to the FAT partition
> - Booting and installation

I read thru those instruction and even if I have some expereince with Linux/Ubuntu did it not look easy.
When it comes to the boot parameter just look at [Grub add boot parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)